# Disable elements when running QThread with PySide/PyQt

Tags: python, qthread, pyside6

This is what I get when I click on the OK button.

[image]

But I would like to disable the two buttons while the `run_action()` is still running and finally reset the `bar` to 0.

This is my current code:

```py
import sys
import time

from PySide6.QtCore import QThread, Signal
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QProgressBar,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
)


class External(QThread):
    progressChanged = Signal(int)

    def run(self):
        progress = 0
        while progress < 100:
            progress += 10
            time.sleep(1)
            self.progressChanged.emit(progress)


class Window(QWidget):
    """The main application Window."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(6, 6, 6, 6)

        self.bar = QProgressBar()
        self.bar.setTextVisible(False)
        self.bar.setValue(0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.bar)

        self.cancel_btn = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.cancel_btn.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cancel_btn)

        self.ok_btn = QPushButton("OK")
        self.ok_btn.clicked.connect(self.run_action)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ok_btn)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def run_action(self):
        self.ok_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.cancel_btn.setEnabled(False)

        self.calc = External()
        self.calc.progressChanged.connect(self.onProgressChanged)
        self.calc.start()

        self.cancel_btn.setEnabled(True)
        self.ok_btn.setEnabled(True)
        self.bar.setValue(0)

    def onProgressChanged(self, value):
        self.bar.setValue(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If you want to enable the buttons and reset the bar *after* the task completion, why are you doing that just after starting the thread? Also, since you know the final value of the completion, can't you just check if `value == 100` in the `onProgressChanged()` and then do what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QThread::`finished`()
>
> This signal is emitted from the associated thread right before it finishes executing.
>
> When this signal is emitted, the event loop has already stopped running.
> No more events will be processed in the thread, except for deferred deletion events.
> This signal can be connected to QObject::deleteLater(), to free objects in that thread.

```
import sys
#import time

#from PySide6.QtCore import QThread, Signal
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

#from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QProgressBar,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
)


class External(QThread):
#    progressChanged = Signal(int)
    progressChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        progress = 0
        while progress <= 100:
            self.progressChanged.emit(progress)
            self.msleep(500)
            progress += 10


class Window(QWidget):
    """The main application Window."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(6, 6, 6, 6)

        self.bar = QProgressBar()
        self.bar.setTextVisible(False)
        self.bar.setValue(0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.bar)

        self.cancel_btn = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.cancel_btn.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cancel_btn)

        self.ok_btn = QPushButton("OK")
        self.ok_btn.clicked.connect(self.run_action)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ok_btn)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def run_action(self):
        self.ok_btn.setEnabled(False)        
        self.cancel_btn.setEnabled(False)        

        self.calc = External()
        self.calc.progressChanged.connect(self.onProgressChanged)
        self.calc.finished.connect(self.onFinished)                     # +++
        self.calc.start()

#        self.cancel_btn.setEnabled(True)
#        self.ok_btn.setEnabled(True)
#        self.bar.setValue(0)

    def onProgressChanged(self, value):
        self.bar.setValue(value)

    def onFinished(self):                                               # +++
        self.cancel_btn.setEnabled(True)
        self.ok_btn.setEnabled(True)
        self.bar.setValue(0)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]